# About database custom module in magento

Tags: php, magento

If my module name in magento is `quote` and look please in code of generate database:

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('quote')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('quote')} (
  `quote_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `surname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `mail` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `message` text NOT NULL default '',
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `created_time` datetime NULL,
  `update_time` datetime NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`quote_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    ");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Which name of table appear in my magento database. And how i know errors of setup db, some logs etc.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you call it in your config.xml? Something along these lines:

```
    <models>
        <quote_mysql4>                
            <entities>
                <quote>
                    <table>table_name</table>
                </quote>
            </entities>
        </quote_mysql4>    
    </models>
```